# Why does this T-SQL variable doesn't retain its value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures

The problem is when it tries to run the following statement which is

```
SELECT @rowCount = COUNT(1) FROM @currentTable
```

I'm getting an error that says "Must declare the variable '@currentTable'."

Here's the full code:

```
CREATE TABLE #RequiredTables (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TableName VARCHAR(200)
)

DECLARE @counter INT
DECLARE @rowCount INT
DECLARE @tableCount INT
DECLARE @currentTable VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(6000)
SET @counter = 1

INSERT INTO #RequiredTables
SELECT 'Areas'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Brands'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CardsEnrolled'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CardsMatrix'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CardsUtilized'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Clients'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Customers'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DoctorMatrix'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DoctorMatrixPromo'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Doctors'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DoctorClass'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Employees'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MedCenters'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'pretagging_dsm_allocations'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'pretagging_new_cards'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'pretagging_data'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'pretagging_cards'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'pretagging_status'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SKUs'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Specializations'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TAs'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Territories'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TerritoryMatrix'

SELECT @tableCount = COUNT(1) FROM #RequiredTables

WHILE @counter <= @tableCount
BEGIN
    SELECT @currentTable = TableName FROM #RequiredTables WHERE ID = @counter
    SELECT @rowCount = COUNT(1) FROM @currentTable
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Comment: Most likely your first SELECT clause is not getting a currentTable so it is null and that's probably because there is no table with ID = counter...

Comment: You cannot write queries this way, you would have to use dynamic SQL

Comment: Sorry, this is a Stored Procedure. 
@cod3Junk13 Actually, I'm getting a value which is Areas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you **can not** pass a tablename to from clause using a variable.

When I tried the error was "Must declare the **table** variable "@currentTable"."

I think when SQL server is executing the query, it is looking for a table variable and **not** a varchar variable.

Hope this helps.